# $\Bbb Z \bmod n$ Rings and How to find $x^{-1}$ inverse

Tags: ring-theory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWwGC.png I tried the question using Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Please don’t use images. Especially one with so little text. Use MathJax.

Comment: $331$ (or $-124$) is the correct answer. Did you use the  *extended Euclidean algorithm*? I suppose you should check the signs in your operations.

Comment: We have *hundreds* of answers which explain how to compute modular inverses (and fractions), e.g. see the linked dupes (and their links), which contain most all known methods.  Note that $\,-124\equiv 331\pmod{\!455}\,$ so $\,[-124] = [331]\,$ in $\Bbb Z/455\ \ $

Comment: dear Amanda, welcome to math.se! :) please do not change what your question is asking after posting it; if you have another question (the one about zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}\big/455\mathbb{Z}$), please make a separate post about it, rather than altering your original.